# d3 Bar Chart Incorrect render order after sorting

Tags: sorting, d3.js, bar-chart, render

I have a bar chart with three bars overlaying each other. First the grey bar chart is rendered, then the salmon one and the the blue one. But when they are sorted this order seems to change randomly, so that sometimes a gray bar is drawn over the other two and then they can't seen.

**Solution:** [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofey/thbqtagj/3/)

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofey/qhrzs176/8/) for this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <div style="text-align:left;">
    <form id="form">
      <strong>Sort by: </strong><span class="clocktime-radio"><input type="radio" name="stack" checked value="clock">Clock time and place </span>
      <span class="racetime-radio"><input class="racetime-radio" type="radio" name="stack" value="race">Race time </span>
      <span class="handicap-radio"><input type="radio" name="stack" value="hand">Handicap  </span>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="race_graph">
  </div>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {
        top: 50,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 100,
        left: 80
      },
      width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Get the data
    var data = [{
        "name": "RT",
        "clocktime": "21:33",
        "handicap": "02:30",
        "racetime": "19:03"
      },
      {
        "name": "KM",
        "clocktime": "22:13",
        "handicap": "00:45",
        "racetime": "21:28"
      },
      {
        "name": "SD",
        "clocktime": "22:15",
        "handicap": "01:45",
        "racetime": "20:30"
      },
      {
        "name": "DK",
        "clocktime": "22:20",
        "handicap": "02:45",
        "racetime": "19:35"
      },
      {
        "name": "BD",
        "clocktime": "22:21",
        "handicap": "02:15",
        "racetime": "20:06"
      },
      {
        "name": "KC",
        "clocktime": "22:21",
        "handicap": "02:00",
        "racetime": "20:21"
      },
      {
        "name": "PM",
        "clocktime": "22:22",
        "handicap": "00:45",
        "racetime": "21:37"
      },
      {
        "name": "NR",
        "clocktime": "22:23",
        "handicap": "01:45",
        "racetime": "20:38"
      },
      {
        "name": "LM",
        "clocktime": "22:25",
        "handicap": "02:15",
        "racetime": "20:10"
      },
      {
        "name": "SL",
        "clocktime": "22:26",
        "handicap": "00:15",
        "racetime": "22:11"
      }
    ]

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%M:%S");
    var timeformat = d3.timeFormat("%M:%S")

    // format the data
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.racetime = parseTime(d.racetime);
      d.handicap = parseTime(d.handicap);
      d.clocktime = parseTime(d.clocktime);
      d.place = +d.place;
      d.points = +d.points;
      d.raceplace = +d.raceplace;
      d.timeplace = +d.timeplace;
    });

    // set the domains and ranges
    var x = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.name
      }))
      .range([0, width]);

    // temporal y-scale
    var y = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([parseTime('00:00'), d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.clocktime
        // return d.handicap
      })])
      .range([height, 0]); //time must increase from 0 to height else racetime and handicap are inverted!!!

    // spacial y-scale (race distance)
    var y1 = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 1200]) //race distance
      .range([height, 0]);

    // points y-scale
    var y2 = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 10]) //points awarded
      .range([height, 0]);

    //****************************
    //***** Main Graph setup *****
    //****************************

    var svg = d3.select("#race_graph")
      .data(data)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Add the X Axis
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .style("font", "7px times")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", ".15em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

    // Add the left Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
        .ticks(7)
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%M:%S")));


    // text label for the y axis on left
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
      .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Time (minutes:seconds)");

    //************************************************************
    //******* BarChart by clocktime *******************************
    //************************************************************

    var rects0 = svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data);

    var newRects0 = rects0.enter();
    // Note: y2(d.points) is the y coordinate of rect
    newRects0.append('rect')
      .attr('x', function(d, i) {
        return x(d.name) + 2;
      })
      .attr('width', 20)
      .attr("transform", "translate(5,0)")
      .style('fill', 'gray')
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return y(d.clocktime);
      })
      .attr('height', function(d, i) {
        return height - y(d.clocktime)
      });


    //************************************************************
    //******* BarChart by racetime *******************************
    //************************************************************

    var newRects1 = rects0.enter();

    // Note: y2(d.points) is the y coordinate of rect
    newRects1.append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'bar')
      .attr('x', function(d, i) {
        return x(d.name) + 2;
      })
      .attr('width', 20)
      .attr("transform", "translate(5,0)")
      .style('fill', 'salmon')
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return y(d.racetime);
      })
      .attr('height', function(d, i) {
        return height - y(d.racetime)
      });

    //************************************************************
    //******* BarCharts by handicap ******************************
    //************************************************************
    var newRects2 = rects0.enter();

    newRects2.append('rect')
      .attr('x', function(d, i) {
        return x(d.name) + 2;
      })
      .attr('width', 20)
      .attr("transform", "translate(5,0)")
      .style('fill', 'blue')
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return y(d.handicap);
      })
      .attr('height', function(d, i) {
        return height - y(d.handicap)
      })
      .attr('class', 'bar');

    d3.selectAll("input[name='stack']").on("change", change);

    function change() {

      var x0 = x.domain(data.sort(this.value == "clock" ?
          (function(a, b) {
            return (new Date(b.clocktime) - new Date(a.clocktime)) * -1;
          }) : (this.value == "race") ?
          (function(a, b) {
            return (new Date(b.racetime) - new Date(a.racetime)) * -1;
          }) : (function(a, b) {
            return (new Date(b.handicap) - new Date(a.handicap)) * -1;
          })).map(function(d) {
          return d.name;
        }))
        .copy();

      svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .sort(function(a, b) {
          return x0(a.name) - x0(b.name);
        });

      var transition = svg.transition().duration(750),
        delay = function(d, i) {
          return i * 5;
        };

      transition.selectAll(".bar")
        .delay(delay)
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return x0(d.name);
        });

      transition.select(".x.axis") //selects the x-axis
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("g")
        .delay(delay);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Maybe when I draw multiple bar charts I should not repeat the code for each as I do and that there is some way to more efficiently draw them which will get rid of the render issue I am having.

Thanks

Comment: I am not seeing the problem in your fiddle - the layer order stays the same for me no matter how many times I sort (using Safari). There is a different problem though. The numbers for `handicap` and `racetime` add up to `clocktime` right? So the bar for `clocktime` should be the height of the total of the other two. In other words `racetime` should start where `handicap` ends. The `d3.stack()` generator makes this pretty easy and lets you draw everything with one pass.

Comment: The render problem only occurs after sorting with the radio buttons. I wonder why that is not happening in the jsfiddle. Yes the numbers handicap and racetime add up to clocktime. However this is not a stacked bar chart. All bars start on the xaxis or at yaxis time 00:00.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to put them beside each other so that each bar could be show fully, but there are almost 200 in each race, so that is why I placed them on top of each other.

Comment: Actually I just had an idea. I could drawn them with no overlay. So that racetime would start on where handicap ends but have a height of handicap less than what it is now and likewise clocktime would start where racetime end and have a height of landicap and racetime less than what it is now. This way the top of each bar would be unchanged.

Comment: it would be best to create three g (group) elements for each bar type, and then add the bars to those. That way the bars will remain in right z order when sorting left to right

Comment: I did get it to work as I described above, https://jsfiddle.net/ofey/thbqtagj/1/ But @TomShanley your way is mush better. I'll try to implement it. thanks

Comment: Also fixed the alignment of axes https://jsfiddle.net/qhrzs176/12/

Comment: Ah brilliant thanks. You grouped them and fixed the axes tick alignment. Much appreciated.

Comment: I am correct to suggest the bars will now always align on the ticks regardless of the number of bars?

Comment: Solution: jsfiddle . https://jsfiddle.net/ofey/thbqtagj/3/